# How to apply TAB on several lines in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, shortcode, tabular

I am wondering if there is a shortcode (MAC) to tab several lines (see example below).

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Last Name"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

->

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Last Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

I looked through the [command list](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf), but couldn`t find something. Maybe there is another way to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sure**. Press (and keep pressed) the `alt-option` command on your Mac, then click with the mouse/touchpad and move upwards/downwards. The effect is the following:

[image]

([source](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/))

Comment: nice! that`s super cool! wish I could give you a "super useful answer" click.

Comment: Glad to hear. Just marking it as regular answer is fine, so that others may find it as well ;)

Answer (score 3):

Select several lines, then press tab to indent them or press Shift + tab to unindent them. This works at least on OS X V10.11.6 with Android Studio V2.1.2. Hope this helps you or people who read this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To tab shift multiple lines in android studio editor:

```
Select lines ( SHIFT-DOWN/UP ) and press TAB key
```

Shift TAB does the same backwards.

Answer (score -2):

You can try with CMD+Shift+L (auto indent)